# MySQL - Stored Procedure limit issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure in SQLYog in MySQL as follows,

> DELIMITER $$
>
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
>   `test`.`spUser`$$
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`spUser`(IN
>   start1 INT,IN limit1 INT)
>
> ```
> BEGIN
> ```
>
> select gi.id,gi.user_id,concat(concat(first_name,' '),last_name) as full_name   from generic as gi, profile as p    where  gi.user_id=p.user_id limit  start1,limit1;
>
> ```
> END$$
> ```
>
> DELIMITER ;

If I have written above code then it throws error no. 1064 and if I have replaced limit start1,limit1 by limit 5,10 then it run properly.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop procedure if exists list_users;

delimiter #

create procedure list_users()
begin
  set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = 1;

  select * from users;

  set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = DEFAULT;
end#

delimiter ;


select * from users;

+---------+----------+
| user_id | username |
+---------+----------+
|       3 | alpha    |
|       2 | bar      |
|       4 | beta     |
|       1 | f00      |
+---------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


call list_users();

+---------+----------+
| user_id | username |
+---------+----------+
|       3 | alpha    |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: SQL_SELECT_LIMIT this variable defines the LIMIT. But what about starting point of record?

Comment: @Ozz give me the big picture - what are u trying to do - pagination ?